# stop and start a service using docker

Tags: linux, docker

I'm very unfamiliar with docker software, I began using it yesterday. I wish to stop a service, dnsmasq, when I run `docker-compose up -d` and the restart the same service when I run `docker-compose down`. I wish to know if this is possible and what do I need to include in my docker-compose.yml file. Currently it's configured this way.

```
version: "3"

services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "67:67/udp"
      - "80:80/tcp"
      - "443:443/tcp"
    environment:
      TZ: 'Asia/Kolkata' #this is the time zone
    volumes:
       - './etc-pihole/:/etc/pihole/'
       - './etc-dnsmasq.d/:/etc/dnsmasq.d/'
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1
      - 1.1.1.1
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to use pihole to replace your local dnsmasq.

**TLDR** : I think it's not possible directly, you have to **write a wrapper**.

## Background

Starting with docker, you have to understand clearly the difference between the *container* (a running instance of the docker image) and the *host* (your machine). That seems clear at first glance, but it tooks me some time to see clearly of implications.

The host runs a container.
It means that the host can act on the container, but the container **can't** act on the host.

And docker (and docker-compose) are focusing on the *container*.

Here, you want to stop dnsmasq running on the *host* when the *container* is started.

I think docker(-compose) won't help you here.
There is an open issue for this kind of things here :
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6736

## Solution : write a wrapper script

For now, you'll have to write a wrapper script that do the actions when you want (stop dnsmasq, then docker-compose up; docker-compose-down, then start dnsmasq)

Either you write a specific script, or a replacement for docker-compose

### Specific script

You can write a specific script (pihole) that handle up and down actions; and you use it instead of docker-compose : pihole up, pihole down

### Decorate docker-compose

The idea :

1. Start with a script that just do :

   ```
    docker-compose "$@"
   ```
2. Put it in your PATH, before `which docker-compose`
3. Prepend your script : parse arguments to find the action (the first non option argument) and the container name, if actions is one of start,stop,kill,up,down (please check this list with the documentation)
4. Prepend your script : if action is one who starts the container pihole, stop dnsmasq
5. Append to your script : if action is one who stops the container pihole, start dnsmasq